# Dynamically set images in custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

can someone explain me what i am doing wrong/what i have to do?

I have a listview that is getting its information from a json array. But it is a custom listview, with 5 images and some text on each row. Each image has a /drawable/image_selector with different images according to enabled/disabled. I am able to dynamically set the text for each row, using hashmap and a ListAdapter. But i am trying to do the same with the images and i am not able to do it. is using a custom adapter the right choice? and if so how? i have not understood from the examples how to use them.

Thanks

here is the code for the given activity:
    public class DisponiveisActivity extends ListActivity {
;
    //para os icones do layout

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//Object of class JSON Parser
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> disponiveislist;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);


    disponiveislist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new Loaddisp().execute();

}
//Background ASYNC task to load

class Loaddisp extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisponiveisActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregando");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }



    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


                String nome = l.getString("NOME");
                String preco = l.getString("PRECO");
                String cfotografia = l.getString("COMFOTOGRAFIA");
                String cdados = l.getString("COMDADOS");
                String copiniao = l.getString("COMOPINIAO");

                String cdeslocacao = l.getString("COMDESLOCACAO");



                String distancia = l.getString("DISTANCIA");

                //create new HASHMAP                    
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                map.put("NOME", nome);  
                map.put("PRECO", preco);
                map.put("DISTANCIA", distancia);
                map.put("COMOPINIAO", copiniao);
                map.put("COMDADOS", cdados);
                map.put("COMFOTOGRAFIA", cfotografia);
                //------------------------------


                disponiveislist.add(map);

            }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */



                    Log.d("PP",disponiveislist.toString());
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DisponiveisActivity.this, disponiveislist, R.layout.listrow,new String[]{"NOME","PRECO","DISTANCIA"}, new int[]{R.id.mission_name, R.id.preco, R.id.cdistancia});




                setListAdapter(adapter);


            }
        });
    }



    }
```

}

Comment: You should probably post your code so we can see if there's something wrong

Comment: just edited with some snippets of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great example I just found on Google:
In this case, you have only one image, I really hope you will understand how to duplicate the code for 5 pictures a row.

```
public class ItemsList extends ListActivity {

private ItemsAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.items_list);

        this.adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, R.layout.items_list_item, ItemManager.getLoadedItems());
        setListAdapter(this.adapter);
}

private class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

        private Item[] items;

        public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Item[] items) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_list_item, null);
                }

                Item it = items[position];
                if (it != null) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image);
                        if (iv != null) {
                                iv.setImageDrawable(it.getImage());
                        }
                }

                return v;
        }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        this.adapter.getItem(position).click(this.getApplicationContext());
}
}
```

Comment: ok, so a for loop using the positions of the items and setting the image drawable would be enough then?

Comment: Yes, of course, or iv1.setImageDrawable(it.getImage1());iv2.setImageDrawable(it.getImage2());iv3.setImageDrawable(it.getImage3());iv4.setImageDrawable(it.getImage4());iv5.setImageDrawable(it.getImage5());